# Use CloudMade on iphone:How can we know if RMMapView load complete?

Tags: iphone

I just start learn to use RMMapView to make some example.As I know, if we use MKMapView we can implement some methods to see loading map status like:

```
- (void)mapViewWillStartLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView

- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView

- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error
```

But if use RMMapView, Does we have any function like that ? I just try to catch even when RMMapView finish load and save data into database.

Thank and best regards for any supporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can fin out a API -(void) regionUpdate: (RMSphericalTrapezium) region; This would be called when tiles are downloaded. To use this you should add a line

```
mapView.contents.tilesUpdateDelegate=self;
```

and should import RMTilesUpdateDelegate.h in .h